# Create select boxes in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make this form: 
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC0Tu.jpg

I have this now but have a few issues.

- The hover needs a border-radius
- Need font a fontawesome icon on right top corner
- How can i change the color of the icon
- The there are three different boxes but only one can be selected. What is the right way to program it.
- Also need to add php later but how.

```css
/* CHECKOUT FORM */

.selection-box {
width: 255px;
height: 180px;
margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
padding: 30px;
border: 1px solid #E3E4EA;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #5A637F;
text-align: center;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: 600;
background-color: #F7F7FA;
}

.selection-box:hover {
outline: 5px solid #76A7E1;
border-radius: 6px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    color: #54637F;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<h1><strong style="font-size: 16px;">Stap 1: kies uw pakket</strong></h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="selection-box"><i class="fa fa-car fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Budget pakket</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="selection-box"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Budget pakket</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="selection-box"><i class="fa fa-car fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Budget pakket</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can use jquery script to do this

Answer (score 0):

Look this: https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/JrLRMp

U need hide .icon and with javascript show it.

```
/* CHECKOUT FORM */

.selection-box {
width: 255px;
height: 180px;
margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
padding: 30px;
border: 1px solid #E3E4EA;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #5A637F;
text-align: center;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: 600;
background-color: #F7F7FA;
}

.selection-box:hover {
border: 5px solid #76A7E1;
border-radius: 6px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    color: #54637F;
}

.icon{
  border-radius: 15px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#76A7E1;
  position:relative;
  top:40px;
  left:235px;
  /*display:none;*/
}

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1><strong style="font-size: 16px;">Stap 1: kies uw pakket</strong></h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="selection-box">
<i class="fa fa-car fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Budget akket</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="selection-box"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Budget pakket</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="selection-box"><i class="fa fa-car fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Budget pakket</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice thanks but it will need to show only when hovering over.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this it may help you No need to use Javascript for this case

```
   <ul id="theme-options1" class="nav nav-pills  custom">
                            <li class="active">

                                <a data-toggle="tab" id="theme1" data-id="1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check them-Selected" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <a data-toggle="tab" id="theme2" data-id="2">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check them-Selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <a data-toggle="tab" id="theme3" data-id="3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check them-Selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <a data-toggle="tab" id="theme4" data-id="4">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check them-Selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

[Here is the Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LSKhan/600p9oyf/)

Comment: you must include libraries

Comment: Yes. I guess I miss jquery.min.js but I can't figure out how to fix this. I'm using Wordpress

Comment: Add all these at the top of your main layout
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

In same sequence

Comment: I already use the libraries. This is my website url:https://www.mijntestservers.nl/werkwijze/

Comment: what issue you are facing now?

Comment: Still the same issue.